# ocaml GADT : why "type a." needed?

Tags: ocaml, gadt, locally-abstract-type

In the basic example of GADT from§7.20 of [ocaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html), what is the meaning of 'type a.' ?
Why declaring "eval : a term -> a" is not enough ?

```
type _ term =
          | Int : int -> int term
          | Add : (int -> int -> int) term
          | App : ('b -> 'a) term * 'b term -> 'a term

        let rec eval : type a. a term -> a = function
          | Int n    -> n                 (* a = int *)
          | Add      -> (fun x y -> x+y)  (* a = int -> int -> int *)
          | App(f,x) -> (eval f) (eval x)
```

Comment: I am no kind of type theorist, but reading through the reference given by @nnarklrh it seems to me the `eval` function requires polymorphic recursion, and the presence of `type a. ...` is in part a signal to turn on support for it. If you leave out `type` you get the errors you'd expect from trying to use polymorphic recursion when not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jacque's [slide](http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~garrigue/papers/ml2011-show.pdf) on ML'2011 workshop has a nice introduction. The idea to use syntax of locally abstract type to introduce universal expression-scoped variable.